# Drawing a triangle with one loop (Revised)

Tags: c, geometry

The triangle should look like this

```
1
11
111
1111
11111
111111
```

the number of rows is entered by the user and then transforms to the function
Note: Without arrays, must be with one loop(while or for) and not nested loops

the closest I got is a code with 2 loop (but can`t think about how to do it with less loops)

```
int i,k;
    for(i=1;i<=x;i++)
    {
        for(k=1;k<=i;k++)
        {
            printf("1");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

The above question was asked by someone but it was marked as off topic I don't know why..?
I came up with this solution tell me if it's correct or not?

```
int i=1,k=1;
    while (i<=x)
    {
        if(k<=i)
        {
            printf("1");
     k++;
     continue;
        }
   i++;
  k=1;
        printf("\n");
    }
```

thanks

Comment: Up to a certain point, you can do it with the expression `x = x * 10 + 1` :-) In any point (1) if the original question was closed, why do you think re-asking it is going to be any better, and (2) you can see if your code is right by _running_ it!

Comment: After the continue; } , you need a k = 1; to reset it for the next row.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot typing that     i++;
      k=1;  ... :)

Comment: @paxdiablo you could get more 1s outputted (only 2) by printing in octal and doing x = x * 8 + 1 (obviously making x an `unsigned long long` will also help).

Comment: Your code only prints one line. You can do with a single loop if you use recursion - can you work out how yourself?

Comment: Can anyone tell me why it was marked as off topic...?

Comment: It appears to be off-topic because it looks like a Code Golf question (and so could/should be in http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/). If there is some real general question here then you haven't managed to make that clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace loops(iteration) with recursion, try this(with one loop):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void draw(int depth)
{
    int i;
    if(depth <= 0) return;
    draw(depth-1);
    for(i = 0; i < depth; i++)
        printf("1");
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    draw(5);
    return 0;
}
```

You can do it even without loop

```
#include <stdio.h>

void draw_num_char(int num)
{
    if(num <= 0) return;
    printf("1");
    draw_num_char(num-1);
}
void draw(int depth)
{
    int i;
    if(depth <= 0) return;
    draw(depth-1);
    draw_num_char(depth);
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    draw(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The question says " must be with one loop(while or for) and not nested loops"

Comment: @Yogeshwar I have improved the answer

Answer (score 1):

Recursive solution, one loop, no arrays.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void liner(int line, int limit) {
    int i;
    if (line > limit)
        return;
    for(i=1; i<=line; i++)
        printf("1");
    printf("\n");
    liner (line + 1, limit);
}

int main() {
    int limit;
    printf ("Enter number of lines ");
    scanf ("%d", &limit);
    liner (1, limit);
    return 0;
}
```